# HTML/JS github pages project doesn't load images or sounds when run with firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Alright so this is a weird one, I'm not entirely sure if this is the right SE site, but I think it is because it regards web code/browser compatibility. If not, someone tell me in the comments I'll move it.

So basically, I have my [game's source code](https://github.com/niwhsa9/Rocket-Blaster-Squad) on github. I also am hosting the game itself on [github pages](http://niwhsa9.github.io/Rocket-Blaster-Squad/). This game should (I believe) function on Firefox and Chrome browsers. The source code has nothing unique to either browser.

The game runs fine on chrome. However, on Firefox this is not the case. None of the assets (images, sounds) are showing up/working on the github pages link. The weird thing is this though: on my local file system, when I open the html file with FF it runs/renders the assets just fine. Also, when I download the zip of my project and try it w/ FF, it also works fine. Why is this the case?

(Note, if you want to see the problem, click on the github pages link, then click on "Start Game", this will open it up to the game where the problem is occuring)

**Edit:** 
Forgot to mention, the error I get in the FF console is `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:` it leads to line 421 which is this: `g2d.drawImage(playerSprite, spriteLoc[0], spriteLoc[1]);` where I draw the image onto the canvas. g2d is supposed to be ctx btw, thats a bad java habbit.

Comment: Do you have any plugins in Firefox that may be blocking it?

Comment: @ayushgp don't think so. Also, its not just me, some people on PPCG chat tried it and had the same problem. Is it working for you on FF?

Comment: It's working on latest build of FF(Nightly) for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the path of the resources.
you call the sound files, and image files this way:

```
laserSound = new Audio("resources\\Sounds\\laserblast.wav");
playerSprite.src = "resources\\Sprites\\Sprite.png";
```

you need to change the path to this:

```
laserSound = new Audio("resources/Sounds/laserblast.wav");
playerSprite.src = "resources/Sprites/Sprite.png";
```

that is change this \ to this /

the current way you are getting it, Firefox does not find where you files are at.

also, why dont you put `init();` at the bottom of the JS file, its just to make sure, that the JS parser already knows that certain functions you will be calling are defined, like `update()` and `initBackground()` (this does not seem to be a problem, but just to be on the safe side.)

Comment: Alright, thanks Sergio. I'll try this as soon as possible after school!

Comment: Yes!! It works perfectly. Thanks. Sorry for the late accept, been busy with hw.

Comment: Just an update, not only does it work w/ FF and Chrome, but it works great w/ Edge too and even a bit with IE... You are a miracle worker, I literally gave up on IE. LOL

Comment: glad I could help.